# Flash Message Error in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

IN my rails application flash message is visible but without its proper blocks and colors.
falsh message "Invalid data double check your field"

[image]

I successfully add bootstrap-sass gem in my gem file. and run bundle install.

Code of flash message .

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div  class="alert alert-<%= key%>">
        <%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
```

Code of Calling flash hash

```
flash[:error] = 'Invalid Data Double Check Your Field'
```

i also require file properly

```
*= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
```

Now how i solve this error?????

Comment: your problem is not clear, please explain, what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no `alert-error` CSS class in bootstrap. It should be `alert-danger`.

If you want, then you can refer to [this article for managing flash messages using Twitter Bootstrap](https://surya.rajtripathi.com/2018/02/rails-4-flash-messages-using-twitter.html). Note that your application doesn't have to be on Rails 4 and using twitter-bootstrap 3(as mentioned in the article), but you can use the same approach to suit your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by " size of flash block"? And, you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it has helped. :)

Comment: flash message is visible in complete line. i want to reduce its size

Comment: Referring to the article I mentioned. I created a gist: https://gist.github.com/suryart/7418454#file-application-html-erb in which you see the the [`flash_messages`](https://gist.github.com/suryart/7418454#file-application-html-erb-L6) method is within a `container` CSS class, did you try that?